# Image gallery preview not displaying correctly in Chrome and Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I've made a image gallery where you can click on an image to display a bigger version of it. When clicking on an image a new image is inserted on the row below. I've gotten a bug and I can't find out how to solve it. For example, if you click on an image on the first row a preview of the image is displayed. Then if you click on an image two rows below, no image preview is shown. It doesn't work in Chrome nor Safari. In Firefox it works great.

Here is the Javascript and jQuery(2.0.3) I use:

```
$(document).on("click", ".imgBox", function(){
    imgsrc = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
    var bigBox = $('<div class="bigBox"><img src="'+imgsrc+'"/></div>');
    imgClicked = $(this);
    $('.bigBox').remove()
    if ($(".bigBox").length > 0){

            bigBox.find('img').attr('src', imgsrc);
            bigBox.insertAfter(imgClicked);
    } else {
            bigBox.insertAfter(imgClicked).css('display', 'block');
    }


});
```

I've created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HeQGL/2/) so that you can try for yourself. Just make sure you resize the browser window so that you get at least 3 rows.

I've tested it in Chrome 30.0.1599.101, Safari 6.0.5 and Firefox 24.0 on OSX.

Comment: Would it be a dealbraker if you specified `width` in .bigBox in `px` instead of `%`? I tweaked a little in CSS, it seems to me that the issue's there.

Comment: that's weird. if you resize the jsfiddle window it appears )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Warning:** This solution is a bit hackery. :)

I noticed that chrome shows this image when I resize the jsfiddle window, as I put it [in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19451525/image-gallery-preview-not-displaying-correctly-in-chrome-and-safari#comment28843116_19451525). So I started to experiment on the ways to "fool" chrome to repaint once again. There are [many ways that cause a repaint](http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2009/03/27/reflows-repaints-css-performance-making-your-javascript-slow/). I chose to manipulate the `style` attribute.

So I created a simple check to set the `overflow` property dynamically from `auto` to `visible` (both these values should not ruin your layout. And I toggle these values when a user clicks an image. Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/HeQGL/5/

P.s. Pay attention though that I changed your script a bit. Changed the element for the event listener, used variables inside the function and used [`.detach()`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) instead of `.remove()` as it suits better when we need to reinsert an element back into the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it in Chrome 30.0.1599.101 m on Windows and it works very good.